# How to connect to SQL Server database with Visual Studio (Windows authentication)

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ssms

It's been a while since I programmed with Visual Studio (Visual Basic) and SQL Server, and I wanted to get back into it.

I've created a database named `LOTTERIE` and on my form I inserted a `DatagridView` which I linked my `.mdf` database file to see all my data on it.

So far it worked.

But I want to be able to add or remove data with a button. In order to do so, I have to make a connection to my db and make query.

I have installed SSMS and created a local DB which the `.mdf` was created on `C:\Users\Amenard`, but then copied in `C:\Users\Amenard\source\repos\Projet1` in Visual Studio when I created my project.

I can connect to my database in SSMS with Windows authentication with no problems.
But I cannot create a connection from Visual Studio in my code to make it work.

Can someone guide me how to do it? And also, I'm connected on a domain that I will call for example `SAQ`.

Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Dim myconnection As SqlConnection

    Dim mycommand As SqlCommand

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader

    Dim ra As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: cette ligne de code charge les données dans la table 'LotterieDataSet.Tirage'. Vous pouvez la déplacer ou la supprimer selon les besoins.
        Me.TirageTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LotterieDataSet.Tirage)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        myconnection = New SqlConnection("server=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;uid=SAQ\Amenard;pwd=screen$;database=C:\USERS\AMENARD\SOURCE\REPOS\PROJET1\BIN\DEBUG\LOTTERIE.MDF")

        'you need to provide password for SQL Server

        myconnection.Open()

        mycommand = New SqlCommand("insert into Tirage([date_tirage],[case_1],[case_2],[case_3],[case_4],[case_5,[case_6],[case_7]) values ('2019-01-01','1','2','3','4','5','6','7')", myconnection)

        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        myconnection.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax , https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Let me confirm again. The title you mentioned is widows authentication while the code shows the SQL Server authentication. I want to know which authentication you wan to use.

Comment: Hi Jack. To make a story short, i created a DB with SSMS wich i log localy with the Windows authentification. I want to connect to the DB in Visual Studio but i get an error message saying that the user or password is incorrect. Yesterday i managed to create a Web.config file in XML that allow the connection. I tested it and seem ok.

Comment: Are you already try to change connection string just like comment from @SamAxe? Remove part uid and pwd, and change to "Integrated Security=true"

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to connect DB in the Visual Studio.

First, you need to choose Tools->Connect to Database->Microsoft SQL Server->Copy the Server Name from ssms and paste into the combox->choose windows authentication->select or enter database name->click ok.

Second, you could open view-> SQL server Object Explorer-> choose the correspond server name-> choose the database->right click properties->choose the connection string-> copy the connection string.

Finally, you can try your code to connect to your database in visual studio.